# Put a Image over an activity

Tags: android, android-layout

How I can put an image over an activity (something like the image below) but with the buttons and other widgets under this image receiving the touch events?

[image http://images.macworld.com/appguide/images/android/558/2908791394402692/5582908791394402692_1.jpg](http://images.macworld.com/appguide/images/android/558/2908791394402692/5582908791394402692_1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem override the draw function.

```
public class TutorialLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

  public TutorialLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    Bitmap tutorial = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tutorial);
    canvas.drawBitmap(tutorial, 0, 0, null);
    tutorial.recycle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transparent `Activity` like this [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android) and make a Layout with a fullscreen `ImageView`

Comment: The previous activity lost the touch events.